# Probability of Hitting Skeet Shots

Tags: probability

The question reads "If the probability of hitting 37 out of 40 shots or more is 4.857 exp(-9), find the probability of hitting an individual shot"
Here is my work

```
P(x > 37) = 4.857 x 10^{-9} 
P(z> $$\frac{37-np}{\sqrt{np(1-np)}) = 4.857 x 10^{-9}$$

and so 37-np/(sqrt{np(1-np)} = -3.5

with n = 40
```

solving for p, I get two positive values, neither of which match the solution of the practice problem. Any tips?

Comment: You should explain where your equations come from.  It appears you are using the normal approximation, which is not valid so far from the mean.  I believe you are expected to use the binomial.  It is only three terms as the question calls for more than $37$.

Comment: Beware that it's "37 or more", not "more than 37" as you seem to state in your first equality : $P(x \gt 37) $ should be $P(x \ge 37)$.